# Julia: Possible to use only 1 parameter for Vector{S} or S

Tags: parameters, julia

**Is it possible to use only one parameter to do the following**

```
type mytype{S}
  x::Vector{S}
  y::Vector{S} OR y::S
end
```

the value y should be able to be a vector of type S or just a single element of type S.

The reason I want this is because really I have

```
y::Dict{Vector{S}, Vector{Int64}}
```

and when the keys are just 1 element in length this is ugly

```
y["key"]   #want this
y[["key"]] #must use this
```

Comment: @Chris Rackauckas's answer is correct, I believe, but I wonder if this is what is what you really meant by the question. With triangular dispatch you get a `y` which is *either* `Dict{Vector{S}, Vector{Int}}` *or* `Dict{S, Vector{Int}}`. You do not get `y` that can take both `S` and `Vector{S}` as keys.

Comment: You can consider keeping `y` strictly of type `Vector{S}`, but then manipulate the getters and setters to accept either `Vector{S}` or `S` as keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need triangular dispatch for this. What you want is

```
type mytype{S,T<:Union{S,Vector{S}}}
  x::Vector{S}
  y::T
end
```

This will come in v0.6, see https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/18457

Comment: I just remembered about Union after I posted this.  Is it possible to just do: 
x::T, y::T
since Vector{S} <: T and keep only the T parameter?

Comment: Well i just tried it and my comment does not work.  I guess once T is selected it is fixed and can't be used for both.

Comment: Yes, what you're looking for is triangular dispatch.